# How to start a notification at a specified time every day?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am a new developer and don't know much about android programming. I am trying to make an app that reminds a user to do a particular thing every day at a specific time (like going to gym at 5:30 pm). I am able to get a notification after clicking of a button but i want this to be done by the app i.e. even if the app is not running it will remind me everyday to go the gym at 5:30. How can I get this???

I tried using AlarmManager but it gives my notification at that time only and sets the alarm for the specified time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example

Answer (score 0):

Set repeating alarm. on broadcast receiver start your notification

Comment: I tried to use broadcast receiver but it is showing one error. I am not getting what to do.`public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  String body="i hope this works";
  String title="trying";
  Intent it=new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
  PendingIntent pit=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, it,0);
  Notification n=new Notification(R.drawable.att,body,System.currentTimeMillis());
  n.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, body, pit);
  n.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
  nm.notify(uniqueId, n);
  
 }`

Comment: it is showing error in `nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: use (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);